# Missing debug information from NASM and GCC

Tags: gcc, assembly, linker, nasm, ld

I am building a small OS exectuable and i have issues with the linking process using NASM, GCC and GNU Binutils.
I am linking multiple types of object files:

- ELF32 object files with dwarf debug info from NASM
- ELF32 object files with dwarf debug info from GCC

When I link toghether these files with a custom linker script and then re-read the degub information, I only find the debug info from the first object file linked (ordered by effective address).

For reference purposes, I'll post a couple of the lines that i use to compile:

```
nasm -g -felf32 -F dwarf entry.asm -o "build/entry.o"  
gcc -c main.c -o "build/main.o" -m32 -mtune=i386 -gdwarf
```

And link:

```
ld -Tlinker.ld -m elf_i386 --nmagic -nostdlib -static -o "build/bootload.elf" -M -g > "build/map.txt"
```

I Use GCC v. 6.2, Binutils v. 2.27 and NASM v. 2.12
I'll post bits of the linker script if needed. Please help, debugging without line  information is very annoying.

Comment: Have you tried without a linker script to see if that's the cause?

Comment: I need the linker script becuse I need to put certain pieces of code at specific addresses.

Comment: I understand that, still, it would be helpful to know whether that's causing the problem or not.

Comment: OK, I will 'try when I get back to the PC, even if I don't know if I'll even be able to link without said script

Comment: Just create a [mcve], doesn't have to be your true code.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by messing around with the linker script, as you suggested. Again, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.
The problem, as suggested by [@Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester)(thanks), was in the linker script.
I was putting every object file section inside the `.text` section of the final ELF file. I'll post some code to explain the old and new, corrected behaviour:

**OLD:**

```
.text : AT(0x800) {
    test.o(*);
}
```

**NEW:**

```
.text : AT(0x800) {
    test.o(.text);
    test.o(.data);
    test.o(.bss);
}
```

All this code is for the linker script.